# Loss of French Nationality by desuetude (50 year rule)

Tags: france, eu-citizens, french-citizens, europe

My father was born in France to a French mother and was later adopted by Americans and was raised in America. He never returned to France. He died young, before reaching the age of 50. I am 33 years old. I would like to know how the time is counted for the descendent if the ascendent dies before 50 years? But more precisely, what is the likelihood that my request for a CNF will be approved given this obstacle?

Comment: welcome! As per the [help], it's best to keep questions to one per post. In addition, asking subjective questions like 'what is the likelihood' is off topic - we can't really guess that or know the details.